# Is this Diffraction?

Tags: reflection, diffraction

As we are able to see the egg, is this diffraction? Is light bending here somehow?

https://www.instagram.com/reel/CrXyD-NLbNl/?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y=

Comment: No, it's simply geometrical optics. Check out this explanation if you're stuck: [What Would Happen If You Went In a Mirror? (The Action Lab)](https://youtu.be/ezUmSO_OAxY).

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a correct explanation

Answer (score 0):

Well, mirrors work by reflection, so that all that is happening for the camera to see the egg.

I really think that this confounds anybody is a psychological effect, where you mentally remain in the frame of the person who cannot see the egg, and then wonder how it got behind the iPad in the mirror. But that's for a different stack-exchange.

Comment: Perfectly, answered, thanks!